# Bound BitmapImage property gets it's value read twice

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Today I've came across a strange behaviour of .NET framework when it comes to binding `BitmapImage` to `ImageBrush` XAML tag.
What I'm doing is trying to create a `BitmapImage` object inside of a property's getter. In some cases, loading of the image may fail (e.g. when the resource isn't found).
Here's code for the property:

```
public BitmapImage BackgroundImg
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return ResourceHelper.GetImage(this.GetType().Namespace, EnumHelper.GetImageUri(MathFunction));
        }
        catch(ArgumentException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

As you may see above, I'm showing a message box each time the resource couldn't be found. The problem which I encountered is that the property is being hit twice, while I'm notifying the view only once (`RaisePropertyChanged(() => BackgroundImg)`). And of course, I'm not calling the property anywhere in the code.

I found solution for this case, which is to change the property type from `BitmapImage` to `object`, however I still would like to know the source of the problem and whether I'm not simply doing something wrong.

So the question is: **what is the reason of the aforementioned behaviour and is there any other solution to this aside from changing the property type to `object`?**

Comment: You should not have logic in your getters. Assuming this is your viewmodel, you even have a View-Method in there. Don't do that. Load your image in the constructor, if it fails, set some error flag or leave the image null. But don't put resource acquisition in your property getters.

Comment: Or if you want to lazy-load the image in the property getter, store the image in a backing field and return that field when the property getter is called the next time.

Comment: It's my VM and the image is being changed based on user's input (combo's selected item to be precise). Where should I load the image then? Should I load all the possible images once and keep them in memory? To be honest, I don't find it efficient.

Comment: Without [a good, minimal, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to know exactly why the property is being read twice. But frankly, regardless of why, it's not unreasonable at all for a property to be read more than once. If you don't want to acquire the resource anew each time, use something like `Lazy<T>` to handle initialization. I also would not call `MessageBox.Show()` from a property getter; very bad form.